# Three.js is blocking the <select> element and also the left click of the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, three.js

You can switch between data visualization in the web application. It first loads the map in this case is that still and image, when you join the page for the first time. As an user you have the option to choose between subject map still an image and the three.js data visualization. But when I run the code of the three.js somehow the `<select>` with `<option>` elements are not responding any more. but the  `<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="comp_exercise" id="">` still works and is select able. it happened after I used `orbit control` from the three.js library.

So far I have tried to remove all the `event.preventDefault();` but it made no difference. also I have looked in the console if the canvas was overlapping the `select` element what it was not. the console is not returning any errors and changing the css or position on the web page of the `select` element does not make a difference either.

the expected is that the `<select>` still works after the three.js codes get runs so that you can change metric but it is not clickable anymore and left click does not work either

the html code thats not working anymore after the three.js codes get runs:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Main metric</label>
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <optgroup label = "Environmental factors">
        <option value="air">Air pollution</option>
        <option value="noise">Noise pollution</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

how the three.js code get activated

```
 <div class="float-left"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm button_toggle_dataviz" onclick="toggle_toDataviz()">Dataviz</button></div>

 var displayMap = false;
 var display3dData = false;
 var displayStory = false;

function toggle_toDataviz() {
  document.getElementById("dataviz_charts").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("dataviz_map").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("form-container-share-story").style.display = 
"none";
  displayMap = false;
  display3dData = true;
  displayStory = false;
  start3DdataViz();
}
```

I am importing these links:

> Tweenmax.min.js
>
> orbitcontrol.js
>
> three.js

the three.js full code:

```
 var booleanCentrum = false;
 var booleanZuid = false;
 var booleanWest = false;
 var booleanOost = false;
 var booleanNoord = false;
 var booleanNieuwWest = false;
 var booleanZuidOost = false;
 var booleanWestpoort = false;

 function start3DdataViz() {
if(display3dData) {
    document.getElementById('data_viz_cubes_update').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('data_viz_cubes_update').setAttribute("style", "height:500px");
    let a = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("data_viz_cubes_update"), null);
    var canvasHeight = parseInt(a.getPropertyValue("height").substring(0, a.getPropertyValue("height").length - 2));
    var canvasWidth = parseInt(a.getPropertyValue("width").substring(0, a.getPropertyValue("width").length - 2));

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, canvasWidth / canvasHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    camera.position.z = 20;
    controls.update();

    $("#data_viz_cubes_update").hover(
        function () {
            noscroll()
        }
    );

    var noscroll_var;

    function noscroll() {
        if (noscroll_var) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.overflowY = "";
            document.body.style.paddingRight = "0";
            controls.enableZoom = false;
            controls.enablePan = false;
            controls.enableRotate = false;
            noscroll_var = false
        } else {
            document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute('style', 'overflow-y: hidden !important');
            document.body.style.paddingRight = "17px";
            controls.enableZoom = true;
            controls.enablePan = true;
            controls.enableRotate = true;
            noscroll_var = true
        }
    }

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor("#e3e0e5");
    renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('data_viz_cubes_update');
    renderer.setSize($(canvas).width(), $(canvas).height());
    canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: "red", transparent: true});

    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        let b = "";
        0 === i ? b = "Centrum" : 1 === i ? b = "Zuid" : 2 === i ? b = "West" : 3 === i ? b = "Oost" : 4 === i ? b = "Noord" : 5 === i ? b = "NieuwWest" : 6 === i ? b = "ZuidOost" : 7 === i && (b = "Westpoort");
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        mesh.material.opacity = 1;
        mesh.name = b;
        mesh.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20;
        mesh.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20;
        mesh.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20;
        scene.add(mesh);
    }

    var light = new THREE.PointLight('white', 1, 1000);
    light.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(light);

    var render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    render();

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse.x = ((event.clientX - rect.left) / canvasWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -((event.clientY - rect.top) / canvasHeight) * 2 + 1;
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
        for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
            booleanCentrum = false;
            booleanZuid = false;
            booleanWest = false;
            booleanOost = false;
            booleanNoord = false;
            booleanNieuwWest = false;
            booleanZuidOost = false;
            booleanWestpoort = false;
            switch(intersects[i].object.name){
                case "Centrum":
                    booleanCentrum = true;
                    break;
                case "Zuid":
                    booleanZuid = true;
                    break;
                case "West":
                    booleanWest = true;
                    break;
                case "Oost":
                    booleanOost = true;
                    break;
                case "Noord":
                    booleanNoord = true;
                    break;
                case "NieuwWest":
                    booleanNieuwWest = true;
                    break;
                case "ZuidOost":
                    booleanZuidOost = true;
                    break;
                case "Westpoort":
                    booleanWestpoort = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('not on object');
            }
            this.tl = new TimelineMax();
            this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.scale, 1, {x: 2, ease: Expo.easeOut});
            this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.scale, .5, {x: 1, ease: Expo.easeOut});
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `e.preventDefault` from click event handler on windows?

Comment: OrbitControls takes over the mousedown/mouseup. You can disable the controller via controls.enabled = false, and the events should propagate. OrbitControls is designed primarily for full page apps where OrbitControls has complete control over the mouse. If you want different behavior, you'll have to toggle its activation, or make a copy of it and modify it to work how you need it.

Comment: @manthrax thanks indeed when I added `controls.enabled = false;` to the `noscroll` function it worked

Comment: OrbitControls has the second parameter, usually it's `var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)`, thus for even listeners it'll use just the renderer's canvas instead of the whole document. So it's better to instantiate controls after the renderer.